# SQL Server : concatenate data result in to a table format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a split function called `func_SPLIT(@Str as varchar(2000))` that will take a string like "123, 456, 789" and split them into a table format like:

```
Column: 
123
456
789
```

So, if I select one single record, I can split that string to the table format... the join them later....

Here is a problem that I am trying to figure out how to do.

Let's say, I have a query:

```
Select Column1, Column2 
from Table1
```

and it returns multiple records as below:

```
Column1     Column2
a           11111, 22222, 33333
b           44444
c           55555, 66666
d           88888, 99999
```

Is there a way I can convert all these values in Column2 into a table format, so I can join them later... like this format below:

```
Column1     Column2
a           11111
a           22222
a           33333
b           44444
c           55555
c           66666
d           88888
d           99999
```

Here is the split funcion

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
                LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END
```

Thank you,

Comment: can we see the split function you have?

Comment: Updated with the split function. thanks for looking into this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) join:

```
SELECT Column1, Data
FROM MYTABLE CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Column2, ',')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e15d/1